# Is there a database that lists all ways of spelling IPA phonemes?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

I'm looking for a list, database, table, etc. of different ways that IPA phonemes (like `/f/`) can be represented (e.g normally just `f`, but also the `gh` in `cough`).

Comment: In all human languages, or in English (any particular dialect in mind)?

Comment: Also which alphabets, abjads, or abugidas did you want to consider? (btw, IPA doesn't have phonemes; it has **phones**, which are independent of languages or writing systems).